# WPF Visual Studio not throwing the right exception

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, exception

I searched the internet but could not find a suitable solution for my problem.
The problem is the following: I have a wpf application which fires event in which i have some code:

```
string result = e.NewValue.ToString();
```

The problem was that visual studio threw me a 'System.Reflection.Invocation Exception' instead of NullReferenceException when e.NewValue was 'null'. The way I realized that there is something wrong with my visual studio was sending the whole solution to my friend and when he tried to do the same visual studio came up with a NullReferenceException and stopped at the right time. I have tried this to both of my computers - Home PC and a Laptop the result was the same on both of the machines. I really think that I messed up something with the settings but can you help me please because I don't get the real exception when working with WPF. Visual studio is 2010 and SP1.

Comment: Can you share some more information? What event is firing?

Comment: With what the event will help you? The event is OnCellValidating in Telerik radGridView but I don't think that the event is in any importance here. It does not show the real exception for me but it shows it for my friend...

Comment: I wanted to know what the event arguments object was.  Knowing the type of 'e' in your example may help someone identify the problem.

Comment: Could you post the whole exception, including its inner exception and the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You or the Telerik control might be catching and rethrowing a different exception somewhere else. Try this:
Open Debug -> Exceptions and mark "Thrown" for CLR exceptions. This way you're telling the debugger to stop whenever an exception is thrown regardless it's handled or not.